# EBC brake pad sizing issue

Tags: brakes, mini-cooper, brake-pad

I’d appreciate some advice please on whether this is normal.

I bought some EBC yellowstuff pads for a track session I had recently. The pads fit the caliper ok and were drivable but they were significantly undersized compared to the OEM pads.

Attached are a couple of pics showing the difference, the main one being the height in the friction material (about 6mm between them).

The company I bought them from said that this is normal but I really struggle to believe this is correct - and worried it might not even be safe.

It’s an F56 2021 Mini Cooper S entirely stock.

I guess my question is whether it is standard practice to run pads that are undersized like this - I’d worry that after time a groove in the rotor surface could emerge and potentially be dangerous

[image: pad surface between OEM and ebc pads][image: OEM pads showing correct proportion compared to rotor][image: EBC pads undersized compared to rotor]

Answer (score 3):

While I don't think this is dangerous, those do not appear to me to be the proper pads for this vehicle.

I had a similar problem with my car a while back and I found out that there were TWO brake options that used two different sized rotors and different pads.  The only parts that differed were the rotors and the pad.

That looks like what is going on here.  The pads look to be for the smaller rotor.

Comment: Thanks yeah I agree it does look like the pads are for a differently sized rotor, I can only find one variant on places like eurocarparts and ebc though - it’s a new facelift from early 2021 tho so wonder if we’re just playing catch-up.